# How to get the exact value of id

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to get the value of the parameter passed in the URL with app.get like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/mytest/:id', function(req, res){

    var idparam = req.params.id;
    var idquery = req.query.id;
    var idbody = req.body.id;

    res.send(idparam);

});
```

So when I pass localhost:3000/mytest/id=266, i get: `id=266` instead of just `266`. And get undefined with `idquery` and `idbody`.

I only want to get the value of the id. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a request like `localhost:3000/mytest/266` where 266 will be matched as id param

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like this `localhost:3000/mytest/266` instead of `localhost:3000/mytest/id=266`

It will be resolved as `req.params.id`